# attach event to dynamically added `video` elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to attach `on error` event to dynamically added `video` elements in their static parent:

```
$("#all-posts").on("error", "video", function() {
  console.log("we caught an error while reading meta-data");
});
```

But it won't work. It only works on initially loaded elements.

Comment: initiate again the event setting process after dynamically loaded the video tag too

Comment: You need to add this code when video load in video-tag

Comment: FYI : The error() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you want to caugh the event `onerror`, I suggest to define the event like this:

```js
var videoElement = document.createElement('video');

videoElement.onerror = function() {
  console.log('we caught an error while reading meta-data');
  console.log(videoElement.error);
};

videoElement.src = 'https://example.com/bogusvideo.mp4';
```

The `src` attribute points to `404` status code, so the event `onerror` is hitted.

You can do the same thing while adding `<video>` tag by jquery:

```js
var videoElement = $('<video>');

videoElement[0].onerror = function() {
  console.log('we caught an error while reading meta-data');
  console.log(videoElement[0].error);
};

videoElement.prop('src', 'https://example.com/bogusvideo.mp4');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```